# WinError 10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it error

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I have a server that receives files from an application and sends to another application.
Although when trying to send the file I keep getting a *[WinError 10061]* error at the *sendSocket.connect(ADDR)* line. Could someone please tell me why this is. I am very new to sockets and would appreciate any help, thanks.

Here is my code for the sending method.

```
import socket
import os
import threading

PORT = 8080
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER,PORT)

def send():
    sendSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sendSocket.connect(ADDR)
    
    file = open("received_image.jpg", "rb")
    size = os.path.getsize("received_image.jpg")

    sendSocket.send("received_image.jpg".encode())
    sendSocket.send(str(size).encode())
    data = file. Read()

    sendSocket.sendall(data)
    sendSocket.send(b"<END>")
    file. Close()

send()
```

Comment: The error means there is nobody listening on that port on that server.  Does if work if you use "127.0.0.1" for the server?  Does your sever bind to 0.0.0.0, or does it bind to localhost?

Comment: What is the server?

Comment: It does not @TimRoberts

Comment: Is the server actually running on the same machine as this code? Because this code is trying to connect to a server on the same machine. However, do note that depending on DNS configuration, `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` is not guaranteed to return a local IP, it might return a network IP instead, which maybe is not accessible from the machine this code is running on.

Comment: Then what address, exactly, does your server bind to?  If it binds to 127.0.0.1, then you have to conenct to 127.0.0.1.  You can't use its external IP address.

Comment: @TimRoberts I looked at it again and it turns out it does work with 127.0.0.1. Thank you for your help